# Environment Variable not showing up

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, visual-studio-code, private-key

I am implementing public private key based authentication and I need to parameters the location where I store my keys. So that, programmatically my jobs can read it from this location and establish the authentication.

I added the below line in the file `/etc/profile`.
`export PRIVATE_KEYS_PATH= "<Some_Path>"`

I logged out of terminal and logged back in and I could see the value of the above variable using either of the commands `echo $PRIVATE_KEYS_PATH` or `env`.

However, same is not getting displayed when I am running either of the commands on Visual Studio Code. Any idea ? Is there a better place where I can mention this environment variable

Comment: There is no space after `=` allowed.